# Cannot send email in Power Automate Flow with "Dynamic Content"

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am creating a simple Form approval process in Power Automate.
I have a sharepoint list with a column name "Manager Email Id" .

In the "send email" option I am selecting " Manager Email Id" from Dynamic Content but its not working. When I am writing email id directly (xyz@gmail.com) - Its working.

How can I dynamically enter Email id of user/manager in send email option ?

[Screenshot of send email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IhEX.png)

Comment: "Manager Email Id" is a text column? does it contains email?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Muhammad Obaidullah Ather already mentioned. It is good to know which data type you have used for the Hire Manager.

Normally when you store peoples names it is very likely that it is a person or group data type column (which allows the selection of a single value). In that case there should be a Hiring Manager Email field in the dynamic content list.

Example of such a setup: [Hiring Manager Email field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5uY9.png)

However, the id suggests that you might be using a column of the lookup data type?